# Why is the XML::simple module in Perl not outputting the expected format?

Tags: xml, perl

I am currently trying to write a Perl function that can write XML to a file.  The recommend module to use is `XML::Simple`. I have written the code below, and I see XML output, but I don't see what I am trying to output. I have attached my code, the result, and my expected output. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;

sub writexmlout {
  my $hashref = {
        'Contracts' => {
           'ShortName' => '123231123'
         },
         'CallStates' => {
            'CallStatesSPR' => {
           'Name' => 'Acknowledged'
             }
         },
         'ContractElements' => {
             'ShortName' => 'test'
         },
         'Calls' => {
             'CHD' => {
                 'FirstName' => 'Ron',
                 'LastName' => 'Rich',
                 'Tel' => '(123)  456-4567',
                 'Sign' => 'B2B',
                 'Email' => 'ron.rich@mavenir.com'
             },
             'SPCallID' => '12',
             'Remarks' => 'Ticket successfully Ebonded',
             'CustCallID' => '6199999'
         }
  };

  # Create object
  my $xml = new XML::Simple( NoAttr => 1,
                             SuppressEmpty => 1,
                             XMLDecl => 1 ,
                             RootName=>'CallData');

  my $result = $xml->XMLout($hashref);
  print $result;
}

writexmlout();
```

Unexpected results

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<CallData>
  <CallStates>
    <name>CallStatesSPR</name>
    <Name>Acknowledged</Name>
  </CallStates>
  <Calls>
    <CHD>
      <Email>ron.rich@mavenir.com</Email>
      <FirstName>Ron</FirstName>
      <LastName>Rich</LastName>
      <Sign>B2B</Sign>
      <Tel>(123)  456-4567</Tel>
    </CHD>
    <CustCallID>6199999</CustCallID>
    <Remarks>Ticket successfully Ebonded</Remarks>
    <SPCallID>12</SPCallID>
  </Calls>
  <ContractElements>
    <ShortName>test</ShortName>
  </ContractElements>
  <Contracts>
    <ShortName>123231123</ShortName>
  </Contracts>
</CallData>
```

Desired results

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<CallData>
 <CallStates>
    <CallStatesSPR>
     <Name>Acknowledged</Name>
    </CallStatesSPR>
  </CallStates>
  <Calls>
    <CHD>
      <Email>ron.rich@mavenir.com</Email>
      <FirstName>Ron</FirstName>
      <LastName>Rich</LastName>
      <Sign>B2B</Sign>
      <Tel>(123)  456-4567</Tel>
    </CHD>
    <CustCallID>6199999</CustCallID>
    <Remarks>Ticket successfully Ebonded</Remarks>
    <SPCallID>12</SPCallID>
  </Calls>
  <ContractElements>
    <ShortName>test</ShortName>
  </ContractElements>
  <Contracts>
    <ShortName>123231123</ShortName>
  </Contracts>
</CallData>
```

Why is this occurring? How come the tag "name" appears which I am not expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to disable attribute folding altogether. The previous answers work only because they have restricted array folding to attributes that exist nowhere in your source. Since your XML has no attributes at all you should set `KeyAttr` to an empty list with

```
KeyAttr => {},
```

which correctly produces the output

```
<CallStates>
  <CallStatesSPR>
    <Name>Acknowledged</Name>
  </CallStatesSPR>
</CallStates>
```

May I add that I believe `XML::Simple` could be a bad choice, and this is unlikely to be that last of your problems. Consider [`XML::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aDOM) or [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) if you begin to lose patience.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`KeyAttr`](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm#KeyAttr_=%3E_%7B_list_%7D_#_in+out_-_important) option:

```
 my $result = $xml->XMLout($hashref,KeyAttr=>{item=>"CallStatesSPR"});
```

I'm not terribly experienced with `XML::Simple`, but from what I can gather, this option tells the parser that you want to consider `CallStatesSPR` to be an item and to put the resulting hash reference inside of `<CallStatesSPR>` tags.

Comment: This enables folding of `item` elements on their `CallStatesSPR` attribute. Since there are no elements that look like `<item CallStatesSPR="xxx">` the option effectively disables folding on attributes, which is what is required to correct the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your responses.  Setting KeyAttr to an empty list did the job. What I wonder now is what do you all mean by a primary key? Primary key for the entire transaction for a database? Do you have any links to describe this?

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyAttr =>` option will allow you to specify item names that you want as primary keys.  In your case, for example, you want `KeyAttr =>  { CallStatesSPR => 'name'}`

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work, it produces `<CallStatesSPR>CallStatesSPR</CallStatesSPR>`.

Comment: @Wes: this works only because there are no elements that look like `<CallStatesSPR name="xxx">` in the data. The effect is to disable array folding altogether, which is what is required.